# How to proceed with evaluating $\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{9+4x^2}}$ and $\int\tan^2(3x)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

> 1. $\displaystyle\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{9+4x^2}}$
> 2. $\displaystyle\int\tan^2(3x)dx$

---

For the first one i'm not sure if I did it correctly, here is what I did:

Let $2x=3\tan(t)$, so $x=\frac{3}{2}\tan(t)$ and $dx=\frac{3}{2}\sec^2(t)dt$. So by substitution,
$$\begin{align}\displaystyle\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{9+4x^2}}&=\int\frac{\frac{3}{2}\sec^2(t)}{3\sec(t)}dt\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int\sec(t)dt\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left(\ln|\sec(t)+\tan(t)| + C\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left(\ln\bigg|\frac{\sqrt{9+4x^2}}{3}+\frac{2x}{3}\bigg|+C\right)\\
\end{align}$$

For the second one, i'm unable to proceed, what I did was

$\displaystyle\int\tan^2(3x)dx=\int\frac{\sin^2(3x)}{\cos^2(3x)}dx=\int\frac{\frac{1}{2}\big(1-\cos(6x)\big)}{\frac{1}{2}\big(1+\cos(6x)\big)}dx=\int\frac{\big(1-\cos(6x)\big)}{\big(1+\cos(6x)\big)}dx$

is this the right way to proceed?

Thanks

Comment: For the second one, use $\tan^2\theta=\sec^2\theta -1$

Comment: For the first one, if you are not sure I suggest that you differentiate the result and see if you end up with the function you started with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put $3x=u
 $ to get $$\frac{1}{3}\int\tan^{2}\left(u\right)du=\frac{1}{3}\int\left(\sec^{2}\left(u\right)-1\right)du=\frac{1}{3}\tan\left(u\right)-\frac{u}{3}+C=\frac{1}{3}\tan\left(3x\right)-x+C.
 $$

Comment: I don't think  you got the integrand correctly. It is a square!!

Comment: @satishramanathan There was a typo, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The first integral is correct.

The second is easier! Substute $3x=t$ and note that $\tan^2 t= \dfrac{1}{\cos^2t}-1$

Answer (score 1):

The first one is correct. For the second one, you can use the hopefully well-known derivative:
$$
D\tan x=1+\tan^2x.
$$
Hence,
$$
\int \tan^2(3x)\,dx=\int 1+\tan^2(3x)-1\,dx=\frac{1}{3}\tan(3x)-x+C.
$$

Answer (score 0):

For the first one, rewrite the integral as follows:

$$ \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{9+4x^2}} \, \mathrm{d} x =  \frac{1}{3} \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+4x^2/9}} \, \mathrm{d} x  =  \frac{1}{3} \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+(2x/3)^2}} \, \mathrm{d} x, $$ now let $v = 2x/3$ so we have:

$$ \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{9+4x^2}} \, \mathrm{d} x = \frac{1}{2} \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + v^2} } \, \mathrm{d}v = \frac{1}{2} \textrm{asinh}{v},$$

where for the last integral we recall that [***[link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_hyperbolic_function#Derivatives)***].